# Expected Value of Y = MIN(X, 100) where X~Geometric

Tags: probability

Let X = Geometric$(\theta)$ and Y = Min(X, 100). Compute E(Y)

My thoughts are:

Y = g(X) = Min(X, 100).
E(Y) = E(g(X))
= $\sum_{x=0}^{\infty} g(X)P(X=x)$
$$= \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} Min(X, 100) P(X=x)$$
$$= \sum_{x=0}^{100} x P(X=x) + \sum_{x=101}^{\infty} 100 P(X=x)$$
$$= \theta (\sum_{x=0}^{100} x (1-\theta)^x) + 100 \theta \sum_{x=101}^{\infty} (1- \theta)^x$$
$$= \theta [\frac{100(1-\theta)^{102}) - 101(1-\theta)^{101}+1-\theta}{\theta^2}] - 100 \theta(\frac{(1-\theta)^{101}-1}{(1-\theta)-1}) + 100 \theta \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} (1- \theta)^x$$
$$= \theta [\frac{100(1-\theta)^{102}) - 101(1-\theta)^{101}+1-\theta}{\theta^2}] - 100 [1 - (1-\theta)^{101}] + 100 \theta(\frac{1}\theta{})$$

$$= [\frac{100(1-\theta)^{102}) - 101(1-\theta)^{101}+1-\theta}{\theta}] +100(1-\theta)^{101}$$

Is this right? It looks really ugly.

Comment: Regarding the closed form, yes -- split up the $x-100$ and you reduce the problem to finding a sum of the form $\sum_n a^n$, a geometric series, and $\sum_n n a^n$, which can be derived by differentiating the expression for a geometric series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \sum_{x=0}^n (x - n) r^x = \dfrac{(n+1) r - n - r^{n+1}}{(r-1)^2}$$

Comment: Thx. I was hoping it wouldn't be this ugly...